# make simple file copying yields "Nothing to be done"

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to simply copy files that are modified using make. Here is the entire Makefile:

```
FILES = www/foo.html www/bar.html www/zap.php

all: $(FILES)

$(FILES): src/$@
    cp src/$@ $@

clean:
    rm $(FILES)
```

After modifying a file `src/www/bar.html`, make does not copy the file:

```
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ make www/bar.html
make: 'www/bar.html' is up to date.
```

Why does make not see the prerequisite has been modified and that the file needs to be copied?

If I run `make clean`, `make` it works (copies all files).

Comment: Automatic variables like `$@`, `$<`, etc. only have values _within the recipe_.  They have no special value in the prerequisites list.  So, `src/$@` expands to just `src/` as the prerequisite, because the `$@` variable is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/$@` is not well-defined. You want

```
$(FILES): %: src/%
```

which declares a pattern rule, and restricts its scope to the files in `$(FILES)`. (You might want or even need to remove this restriction.)